# S3 upload triggers DynamoDB Write, but GET call to DynamoDB needs to be delayed

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

My apologies in advance for not coming up with a more succinct title.

After successfully uploading a file to S3, it triggers a Lambda function to write data associated with the file such as the S3 key and file size to DynamoDB.

The Client (React.js) then makes an asyc call `getAllFiles` to DynamoDB, but the result is missing the latest Write triggered by the S3 upload. Why? Probably because the DynamoDB table has not been written yet. If I `setTimout` for 2 seconds before making the `getAllFiles` call, then the latest Write is returned.

```
await s3Upload(newFile)
const res = await getAllFiles()
console.log(res) //missing newFile
```

But if I do this:

```
await s3Upload(newFile)
setTimeout(async () => {
const res = await getAllFiles()
  console.log(res) //newFile returned
}, 2000)
```

`setTimeout` is not the best solution. I'm wondering if there is an overall better approach. Maybe DynamoDB Streams can notify the Client when the Write is completed, but I have not been able to find anything on that.

I guess I can give up the S3 trigger and just make a Write call from React to DynamoDB, but that has its own downsides. The trigger seems like a very appropriate approach and I would like to keep it, even if it means sticking with setTimeout. If nothing else, it saves me an HTTP call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you do not want to have your client pull for updates, a push based approach would be more efficient. I have had use-cases like this in the past were I have used Amazon API Gateway Websocket API's.

When your application uploads a file to S3, the client (react app) should also subscribe to your websocket. Once the item is persisted in DynamoDB, use DDB Streams to invoke a Lambda function which will pass the message via the WebSocket back to your client.

No pulling or timeouts needed and your client gets the information as close to real time as possible.

[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) [WebSocket API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html)

[2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html) [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html)

[3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) [Lambda Consumer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Comment: Thank you Lee. I'll read up on WebSocket API and see how this can be implemented.